# Sequelize-Typescript One To Many Association with Repository returns 1 child entity when there's more than one

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have been working around using Sequelize-Typescript and I have stumbled upon the one-to-many association. Here I have "Album" and "Photos" as my entities. One "Album" has many "Photos". So here's my entity codes for your reference:

***Album.ts***

`

```
@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  deletedAt: "albumDeletedAt",
  paranoid: true,
  createdAt: true,
  updatedAt: true
})
export class Album extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column({
      type: DataType.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
  })
  declare id: number;

  @Column({
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false
  })
  declare name: string;

  @Column({
     type: DataType.STRING,
     allowNull: true
  })
  declare description?: string;

  @Column({
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false
  })
  declare thumbnailURL: string;

  @HasMany(() => Photo)
  declare photos: Photo[];

  @CreatedAt
  declare createdAt: Date;

  @UpdatedAt
  declare updatedAt: Date;
 }`
```

***Photo.ts***

```
import { BelongsTo, Column, CreatedAt, DataType, ForeignKey, Model, PrimaryKey, Table, 
UpdatedAt } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { Album } from "./album";

@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  deletedAt: "photoDeletedAt",
  paranoid: true,
  createdAt: true,
  updatedAt: true
})
export class Photo extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column({
      type: DataType.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
  })
  declare id: number;

  @Column({
     type: DataType.STRING,
     allowNull: false
  })
  declare name: string;

  @Column({
     type: DataType.STRING,
     allowNull: false
  })
  declare photoURL: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Album)
  @Column({
     type: DataType.INTEGER,
     allowNull: true,
  })
  declare albumId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Album)
  declare album: Album;

  @CreatedAt
  declare createdAt: Date;

  @UpdatedAt
  declare updatedAt: Date;
}
```

***AlbumRepository.ts***

```
export class AlbumRepository {
private albumRepository: Repository<Album>;
private photoRepository: Repository<Photo>;

/**
 * This constructor injects the DatabaseMiddleware class created and annotated as "@Service()"
 * @param databaseMiddleware Database Middleware created
 */
constructor(public databaseMiddleware: DatabaseMiddleware) {
    this.albumRepository = databaseMiddleware.getDatabaseInstance().getRepository(Album);
    this.photoRepository = databaseMiddleware.getDatabaseInstance().getRepository(Photo);
}

/**
 * Creates an "Album" data in the database.
 * @param albumCreateDTO Album Create DTO data model
 * @returns "Album" data entity model (if successfully created in the database) or null.
 */
public async createAlbum(albumCreateDTO: AlbumCreateDto) {
    try {
        return await this.albumRepository.create({ ...albumCreateDTO }, { include: [this.photoRepository] });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error while creating an album data to the database due to", error?.message);
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Find the album via it's ID
 * @param id The ID of the album
 * @returns Album (if exists) or null
 */
public async getAlbumById(id: number) : Promise<Album | null> {
    try {
        return await this.albumRepository.findByPk(id, { include: [this.photoRepository] }) ?? null;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error finding the album via ID for the ID of ${id} due to`, error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

And finally, my Sequelize-Typescript instance which is below:

```
export default class DatabaseMiddleware {
private databaseInstance: Sequelize;

constructor() {
    this.databaseInstance = new Sequelize({
        dialect: "mysql",
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
        username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        port: 3306,
        // storage: process.env.DATABASE_STORAGE_PATH,
        logging(sql, timing) {
            console.log("The SQL statement from Sequelize executed is", sql, timing);
        },
        query: { raw: true }
        models: [User, Album, Video, Photo],
        repositoryMode: true
    });
}

public async connectToDatabase() {
    try {
        await this.databaseInstance.authenticate();
        if (process.env.ENVIRONMENT_PROFILE === "development") {
            await this.databaseInstance.sync({ alter: true, force: true });
        }
        console.log("Connection to database has been established successfully");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Unable to connect to database due to", error);
    }
}

public getDatabaseInstance() {
    return this.databaseInstance;
}
```

}

I'm using class based style to create the Express.JS REST API and I'm adding dependency injection in every class that I use except the entities. I'm able to create an "Album" with the "Photos" and I'm able to see it on the database. But it's when I call the `getAlbumById` function in the repository that I only get 1 "Photo". If I have inserted 3 "Photo"s then, during the invocation of the function, it returns only 1 "Photo" when there's 3 of them in database.

**UPDATE OF THE QUESTION'S DESCRIPTION**

Here's how the query looks like after running with `include: [this.photoRepository]` in the `AlbumRepository.ts`.

*First screenshot*
[image: 1st Screenshot of the updated query]

*Second screenshot*
[image: 2nd Screenshot of the updated query]

If you have any solution, please do share them here. Thanks!

Error when removing `raw: true` flag from the `AlbumRepository.ts` which is the function `getAlbumByID`:

***Error finding the album via ID for the ID of 1 due to TypeError: result.get is not a function
at E:\Coding Projects\Projects\Back-Ends\Profilic\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:1885:39
at Array.reduce ()
at E:\Coding Projects\Projects\Back-Ends\Profilic\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:1884:19
at Array.map ()
at Function._findSeparate (E:\Coding Projects\Projects\Back-Ends\Profilic\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:1881:39)
at Function.findAll (E:\Coding Projects\Projects\Back-Ends\Profilic\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:1840:24)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Function.findOne (E:\Coding Projects\Projects\Back-Ends\Profilic\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:1998:12)
at async Function.findByPk (E:\Coding Projects\Projects\Back-Ends\Profilic\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:1955:12)
at async AlbumRepository.getAlbumById (E:\Coding Projects\Projects\Back-Ends\Profilic\repositories\album.repository.ts:52:20)***

Comment: Did you look at generated SQL?

Comment: I can't add the generated SQL statement as StackOverflow says it's long but I can it does a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on Album ID

Comment: Does the generated SQL return the correct result?

Comment: @Anatoly, unfortunetely no. If there's 3 "Photo"s hooked to a single "Album", it needs to return all 3 "Photo"s. Instead, it returns one "Photo" and the way it returns is like this "photo.id": 1, "photo.name": "Earth", instead as an child object. You can check the response I get from Sequelize-Typescript

Comment: The response I obtain from sequelize-typescript repository style
`{
    "name": "Earth",
    "description": "Earth from the galaxy",
    "thumbnailURL": "http://192.168.1.15:8080/uploads/pictures/galaxy/earth.jpg",
    "albumDeletedAt": null,
    "photos.id": 1,
    "photos.name": "3840x2880_2887b808096152458f8e6b41cb5a8780.jpg",
}`

Comment: @Anatoly, I've updated the description of the question so you may know the SQL query generated by sequelize-typescript using repository mode. It has 2 screenshots of it for you and others to see.

Comment: Did you try to remove `raw: true`?

Comment: If I remove the `raw: true` flag, although I've added it in my `database.middleware.ts`, I get this error --> "Error finding the album via ID for the ID of 1 due to TypeError: result.get is not a function"

Comment: Could you show the code in the post related to this error?

Comment: It's in the question's description in under **AlbumRepository.ts**, where the function `getAlbumID(id: number)`. Also take note that I also supply `raw: true` in the `DatabaseMiddleware.ts` file where it's in `query : { raw: true }` as well.

Comment: Can you remove `raw: true` from DB settings as well?

Comment: Removed it from the database settings as well. Still the same issue.

Comment: Can you add the error and stacktrace on to the post?

Comment: I added the error and stacktrace and have updated the code snippet in the post

Comment: Could you also update the screenshots (or better change them to code blocks) to the latest ones without any `raw: true` options?

Comment: Which screenshots you meant? Because the screenshots I've attached are basically generated Sequelize when a query or a code is executed? The above codes have already been updated

Comment: At least I can see the first screenshot still contains `raw: true`

Comment: I've updated the screenshots, there's a new error after removing `query : { raw: true }` in the database middleware & `raw: true` in the album repository as well

Comment: Does the query work without `include` option? Did you try `include: [{ model: this.photoRepository }]`?

Comment: Still the same error as it's in the screenshot I've updated

Comment: And without `include`?

Comment: Without `include`, you get the data of `Album` only without the `Photo`s linked to it

Comment: I know, just to make sure that it's `include` option that brings the error

Comment: Sorry, you wouldn't get an error but you get the data in forms of `dataValues`, `_previousDataValues` and etc. In the `dataValues`, I can assure you that the `Photo` does not come with it since it's not "included" with it.